How do I find i2c address of an IC
I am using the M41T0M6F chip and trying to find the i2c address expected. How can I find the address? I couldn't find it in the datasheet or from a tech documentation.
I wanted to be able to know if it is showing up correctly with i2cdetect.
For example in https://learn.adafruit.com/scanning-i2c-addresses/raspberry-pi they are using an BMP280 breakout board. BMP280 is documented to have an address of 0x76.

Did you try to run i2cdetect as mentioned in the article?

You haven't really tried looking.  I typed M41T0M6F in google and the second result is the datasheet for this on the manufacturer's website.
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/m41t0.pdf
In figure 7 you can see that the address is binary 1101000, or hex 0x68.

Ah I missed that. I did see that datasheet but I was looking for a hex not a binary address. Thanks for that.
